# Using Rx.Observable from event with pausable does not run the subscribe function

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable

Note: I am using typescript with rxjs(2.5.3) here

I am trying to determine idle click times on a screen for 5 seconds

```
var noClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>($window.document, 'click')
                .bufferWithTime(5000)
                .filter(eventBundle => {
                    return eventBundle.length === 0;
                });
```

This is the subscribe function

```
var noClickStreamSubscriber = noClickStream.subscribeOnNext(() => {                                   
                this.showLogoutWarning = true;
});
```

This runs the code fine. The subscriber gets called when there is no click for 5 seconds.

Now, I actually want to be able to pause and resume the noClickStream in the subscribe function when the warning screen is being shown. For this I added pausable() to the initial no click stream.

```
var noClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>($window.document, 'click')
            .bufferWithTime(5000)
            .filter(eventBundle => {
                return eventBundle.length === 0;
            })
            .pausable();
```

Now the **noClickStreamSubscriber** function never gets called even after 5 seconds of no click activity. Does fromEvent not support pausable functionality?

Comment: Changing Rx.Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>($window.document, 'click')
to:
Rx.Observable.fromEvent<Event>($window.document, 'click') did not help either

Comment: `pausable` should work, but you are not using it correctly. It takes an observable `pauser`: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/v.2.5.3/doc/api/core/operators/pausable.md

Comment: Actually I found the reason, I never started the stream in the first place. The moment an observable is set as pausable, one needs to resume it initially. Otherwise it just won't run. Duh, I spent like 5 hours on this :/

Comment: You should answer your own question so that it's no longer listed as unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: thanks for that piece of info @cartant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the subscribe function not executing when the observable is declared as pausable is that the event stream starts in paused state. To get the stream to work, after the subscribe function is defined, noClickStream.resume() must be invoked.

```
var noClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>($window.document, 'click')
            .bufferWithTime(5000)
            .filter(eventBundle => {
                return eventBundle.length === 0;
            })
            .pausable();

var noClickStreamSubscriber = noClickStream.subscribeOnNext(() => {                                   
                this.showLogoutWarning = true;
});

noClickStream.resume(); // This has to be invoked
```